# AttributeError: 'person' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, class, methods, syntax-error, spyder

```
class Name():
    def full_name(self):
        self.firstname='[no name]'
        self.lastname='[no name]'

class person:
    def detail(self):
        self.name=Name()
        self.eye='[no eye]'
        self.age=-1

myperson=person()
myperson.name.firstname='apple'
myperson.name.lastname='regmi'
myperson.name.firstname='cat'
print(myperson.name.firstname)
```

i could not find out why iam getting  line 13, in 
    myperson.name.firstname='apple' AttributeError: 'person' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Obviously you can't access `myperson.name` because you didn't run `myperson.detail` at first so `myperson.name` have not been defined yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're hoping to set the `name`, `eye`, and `age` attributes as defaults when you create any `person` object. If that's the case, `detail` should really be replaced with `__init__`, e.g.:

```py
class person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=Name()
        self.eye='[no eye]'
        self.age=-1
```

A class's `__init__` method defines how objects should be initialized when they are created. You don't need to call this method explicitly; instead, it is automatically run when you create an instance of a class:

```py
# create an instance of persion, call
# `person.__init__()`, and assign the result
# to `myperson`:
myperson = person()
```

Now you should be able to reference and assign the attributes:

```py
myperson.name.firstname='apple'
myperson.name.lastname='regmi'
myperson.name.firstname='cat'
```

Similarly, `name.full_name` should probably be `name.__init__`.

Note that by [convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), classes in python usually use TitleCase, so this class would typically be named `Person`; likewise, `name` would be `Name`.